# NewUpdate on Android Addressbook overwrites all contacts

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an App with Xamarin Android in which I try to update the Address of a contact in the android addressbook. I can create a new contact with all the information. With the following code I can insert a new addresses to an existing contact as well:

```
private void InsertAddresses(long rawContactId, IReadOnlyCollection<AddressBookAddress> addresses)
        {
            if (addresses == null || addresses.Count == 0) return;
            var ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();
            // Address
            foreach (var address in addresses)
            {
                var builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, rawContactId);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentItemType);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Street, address.Street);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.City, address.City);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Postcode, address.Postcode);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Pobox, address.PoBox);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Country, address.Country);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonColumns.Type,
                                  (long) GetAddressDataKind(address.AddressType));
                ops.Add(builder.Build());
            }

            context.ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
        }
```

Now I wanted tried to update an existing address instead of Insert it again. So I adjusted the code above to this:

```
            var builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, rawContactId);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentItemType);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Street, address.Street);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.City, address.City);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Postcode, address.Postcode);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Pobox, address.PoBox);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Country, address.Country);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonColumns.Type,
                              (long) GetAddressDataKind(address.AddressType));
            ops.Add(builder.Build());
```

Basically I replace NewInsert with NewUpdate. But this has the effect that it overides all of my contacts. See these screenshots:

Before:

[image]
[image]

After:
[image]
[image]

Since it works in the insert, I assume that the selection method over the RawContactId is correct and that the Id itself is fine as well. Or do I have to select  this differently on an update?
What else could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this part:

```
builder.WithSelection(
                    ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId + "=? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "=?",
                    new[]
                    {
                        rawContactId.ToString(),
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentItemType,
                    });
```

For the update you have to have a selection otherwise it will update everything.